# QuartzScheduler Schedule Job instances instead of JobDetail

Tags: quartz-scheduler, scheduler

I want to schedule Job instances instead of JobDetail.
So something like schedule(Job job, Trigger trigger) ?
Does exists possibility do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you can't schedule a `Job`. You have to use `JobDetail`.

`Job` is just an interface with an `execute()` method. It doesn't offer a way to obtain the job's name, or the job's key, or the job's data map, or whether it's a durable job, or any of the required info that Quartz needs to properly manage the job.

That's why the class `JobDetail` exists, so you can have all that info in a different object that you can instantiate only when you need to, instead of having to implement all those methods in your `SomeJob implements Job` class. You can even create multiple `JobDetail` objects for the same Job class with different properties, as long as you give them different IDs.

There's no reason not to use it, IMHO.